# What does it mean to have sole ownership of object for unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, ownership-semantics

I know that `std::unique_ptr` is used when an object has only one owner and `std::shared_ptr` is used when an object has multiple owners. What does it mean to be the unique owner of an object?

Does being the unique owner mean that nobody else gets to see the object?

Can I return the raw pointer using the `get()` method when passing the pointer as a reference?

I feel that if I have to use `get()`, then I have either transfer ownership by using `std::move`, or use a shared pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ownership is all about: who cleans up the resource when it is no longer needed?

To be the only owner of a resource means that only you are responsible for deleting the object when it is no longer needed. This implies that nobody else can use the object after your lifetime ended. If others depend on the object still being alive after your lifetime ended you need shared ownership.

In modern C++, raw pointers should not participate in ownership. When you pass a raw pointer to a function you expect that this function will not hold on to this pointer to use it later.

Answer (score 2):

Ownership talks about how is responsible about the lifetime of the object.

Let say you have a class `shape` that on which you can do various actions like, calculating the surface area, enlarging or shrinking that object, ...

And those tasks are performed by free functions `calculate_shape_area`, `enlarge_shape`, `shrink_shape`, and you pass the shape to that function, then those functions don't require ownership over that object, they only need to know the object while they are called. So you can (and should) pass that object as raw pointer:

```cpp
struct shape {};

double calculate_shape_area(shape* obj) {
   // calculate the area, obj is only used within that function
   // and not stored anywhere else
}

int main() {
  auto obj = std::make_unique<shape>();
  auto area = calculate_shape_area(obj.get());
}
```

If you, on the other hand, want to store that shape in a scene graph using `insert` and that scenegraph, at a later step, displays all shapes. Then the scenegraph needs to know about that object after the call of `insert` so it either needs to create a copy of it or needs to claim ownership over it. And if you don't want to create a copy then you either need to move a `unique_ptr` to that `insert` or use `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

> But whet does it means to be the unique owner of an object?

Ownership means being responsible for the lifetime of the dynamic object (or more generally, a resource): When the owner ends the lifetime of the owned object, it is responsible for cleaning up (deallocate memory). Furthermore, the owner does not need to worry that lifetime of the object is ended by something else.

Being unique simply means that no other object can share the ownership.

> Does being the unique owner means that nobody get to see the object?

No. Encapsulation is an orthogonal concept.